# Struggling to understand ambiguity errors C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

The primary error is:
Ambiguity between `ContentTypeCreator._contentTypeService` and `ContentTypeCreator._contentTypeService CS0229`

This is basically a copy of boiler plate from the source documentation. I don't understand why the ambiguity error is with self. I don't see how this is redundant? Thank you.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Strings;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class ContentTypeCreator
    {
        private IContentTypeService _contentTypeService;
        private IShortStringHelper _shortStringHelper;

        public ContentTypeCreator(IContentTypeService contentTypeService, IShortStringHelper shortStringHelper)
        {
            _contentTypeService = contentTypeService;
            _shortStringHelper = shortStringHelper;
        }

        public void CreateContentType(string alias, string name)
        {
            // Check if the content type already exists
            var contentType = _contentTypeService.Get(alias);
            if (contentType != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new content type
            ContentType contentType1 = new ContentType(_shortStringHelper, -1)
            {
                Alias = alias,
                Name = name,
                Description = "Generated by ContentTypeCreator",
                Icon = "icon-document", // Set the icon for the content type
                AllowedAsRoot = true, // Allow this content type at root level
                IsElement = false // This is not an element type
            };
            contentType = contentType1;
            // Save the new content type
            _contentTypeService.Save(contentType);
        }

        private string GetDebuggerDisplay()
        {
            return ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using fully qualified names and assigning values to variables.

Comment: Potentially you have two different DLL versions of the same contentTypeService. Try to Clean -> Rebuild your application

Answer (score 0):

Ambiguity happens when 2 or more types having the same name. Oftentimes it is happening when you import 2 namespaces that contain same-name types.

```cs
using AmericanCars;
using GermanCars;

var x = new Car(); // compiler error because both namespaces have cars.
```

The potential fix

```cs
var x = new AmericanCars.Car();
var y = new GermanCars.Car();
```

You can also have multiple references of the same assembly but different versions. This will give you multiple same namespaces containing multiple same objects. In this case, you need to give your assembly an alias in the property window, and proceed as in example above ^^. Or additionally to assembly alias, instead of full namespace, use namespace alias.

[image]

And yes, as one of the comments suggested, it is possible that during project manipulations in your [normally] `obj` folder, you get different versions of assemblies that referenced. You need to clean/rebuild. And besides that, sometimes reloading projects and even reloading visual studio helps. Early versions of VS2022 was notorious for loosing reference mapping after long use. Good idea to close the VS before working on different projects.